# How can I condition a slackSend in a Jenkins pipeline job on individual test results?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, spock, jenkins-pipeline

In a Jenkins pipeline job, I want to send slack notifications for individual test results.  I have a gradle build running spock tests which generates an xml file with test results.  Is there any way to access individual test results without having to parse the xml file?

Something like:

```
if(test_results.TEST1 == 'failure'){ 
    slackSend color: 'danger', message: "TEST1 Failed - ${env.JOB_NAME}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java'
ext {
    jenkinsFlag = System.properties['jenkins'] == 'true'
}
test {
    if (jenkinsFlag) {
        afterTest { TestDescriptor desc, TestResult result ->
            if (result.resultType == TestResult.ResultType.FAILURE) {
                slackSend color: 'danger', message: "$desc failed - ${env.JOB_NAME}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

@see [Test.afterTest(Closure)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html#afterTest%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)

Comment: I'm getting the error `Could not find method slackSend() for arguments [test slack send] on root project 'job.Disk_Util'.`

Comment: Hahaha... Of course! You'll need to write that bit!

Comment: well slackSend is a jenkins pipeline method so I wouldn't be writing that.  I thought that you were saying that I could call slackSend from gradle but I'm guessing that's not the case.  Not sure this will work then

Comment: Looks like someone's implemented [slack in java](https://github.com/Ullink/simple-slack-api) which you could easily call from gradle